# php replace content between tags and keep them

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to replace the content between those tags and keep the tags

```
$source="Original string <p>bal bla bla</p>**** <!--{date}-->REPLACE ME!!!<!--/{date}-->"
$replaceText = '2012-06-14';
$start = '<!--{date}-->';
$end = '<!--/{date}-->';

preg_replace('#('.preg_quote($start).')(.*)('.preg_quote($end).')#si', '$1'.$replaceText.'$3', $source);
```

The result is:

```
"Original string <p>bal bla bla</p>**** 012-06-14<!--/{date}-->"
```

Missing the start tag and the 2.
Ideas?

Comment: Put a space between the var and the replaceText like my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because doing like this you obtain :
`'$12012-06-14$3'` as the replacement. So I'm guessing it's taking `$12` and not `$1`

You may want to test what's written in the doc `${1}` instead of `$1`

Answer (score 1):

Put a space between the var and the replaceText

Like that

```
preg_replace('#('.preg_quote($start).')(.*)('.preg_quote($end).')#si', '$1 '.$replaceText.' $3', $source);
```